# Only turn on 2 toggles at a time

Tags: jquery

I have 6 filters and the jQuery functionality to toggle an "on" class if you click them.

How would I code functionality so that only 2 buttons at a time can be "on"?

For example, if you click 1 then 3, they will both be "on". However, if you clicked 4, the oldest button (1) will toggle off and then 4 will toggle on.

Comment: Anything to show us ? Your HTML-markup and/ or your javascript ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to keep track of the order that you toggled the filters on.

```
var filters = [];
var filters_max_on= 3;

$('.filter').click(function(){
   //turn the filter on
   $(this).addClass('on');
   //add it to the front of the array
   filters.unshift($(this));
   //check if there are too many filters active
   if(filters.length > filters_max_on){
      //remove the filter from the list and turn it off
      filters.pop().removeClass('on');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dmo38a1/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8ydujdjq/

```
<style>
.toggle a { color:green; }
.toggle a.on { color:red; }
</style>

<div class="toggle">
  <a href="#">1111</a>
  <a href="#">2222</a>
  <a href="#">3333</a>
  <a href="#">4444</a>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    var selected = [null, null];
    $('.toggle a').click(function() {
        if(selected[0] != null)
            selected[0].removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('on');
        selected[0] = selected[1];
        selected[1] = $(this);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you would have posted what have you tried. Do read this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The method would be:
 1. Save the id's of buttons in an array
 2. Check it more than two have been selected
 3. On click update the array and change the class

```
var onButtons = [];
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    if(onButtons.length == 2){
        $('#'+onButtons[0]).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        onButtons.splice(0, 1);
    }
    onButtons.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oy60c5ve/)